# My toggle button is not working. Could somebody please look at this navbar markup and tell me what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

[![enter image description here][1]][1][![I want the fixed navbar to collapse and be toggle-able on smaller screen. However nothing is happening. ][1]][1]

Below is the code snippet from head section. Any help is appreciated

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TinDog</title>

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Ubuntu" 
    rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384- 
    Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js">. 
    </script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
    KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script 
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384- 
    ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384- 
    JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head>
```

This is the code for my navigation. It works perfectly fine but the toggle doesnt work when the screen is smaller.

```
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data- 
      toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" 
      id="navbarTogglerDemo02">

          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Im pretty sure you are missing a javascript import from bootstrap that goes at the bottom of the body tag, not all of the imports go in the head so double check that

Comment: It doesn't show anything. And when I look into console, there are a lot of errors like.. _The script element has a malformed hash in its integrity attribute:_, or _The integrity attribute does not contain any valid metadata._. Make sure that you post code that can be reproduce the problem.

Comment: Value inside attribute must not enter to wrap new line. For example: `integrity="blabla-no-newline-here"`. The attribute name is the same, it must not add space between dash and do not add new line. For example: `data-name-must-no-space-no-newline="blabla"`.

Comment: @vee there is no newline in actual code. It is giving new line in stackoverflow because of spacing and indentation. All the javascript were directly copied from the bootstrap without any changes. I am really new to coding so it would be so much better if you could suggest me in detail. Thank you for the response

Comment: You have a script tag with a single period in `<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js">. </script>`

Comment: Stack Overflow never give new line automatically, you did this. You have to verify your code to be exact match with your actual code (in this case). I'm already suggested you all the problem, no new line in values, no space or new line in attribute name. Please carefully read my comment above, it is already described and I have tested and work.

Comment: It worked! I appreciate everyone’s help.